# Handling a lot of screens in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm building a online learning platform with react native, and i have a problem.

The learning platform i am going to build has over 200 video's, how am i going to manage that? do i need to make 200 screens and navigate to them or are there reusable screens were i can send props to?

There is also a user authentication in the app with different levels of permission, some lessons are locked for some users and some are free to watch.

i already tried to make a few screens but i think there is a better way.

Comment: Is it true that the video files are on the net ? (say http://www.server.com/video1.mp4,  http://www.server.com/video2.mp4, etc )

Comment: You must reuse the screen but you need to manage data according to the user permissions and all, not according to screen :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a better way. You can make a screen that is free to use without authentication and another one that requires authentication to be used.
After that you can send the array of videos with different id in them, by using the id's in the url.
Being a beginner may be it's becoming difficult for you to understand, so I will recommend you to watch some online tutorial from YouTube where the instructor is sending products to different screens of an e-commerce store.
You will definitely get the idea on how to implement your system from there.